# Error when compiling. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: scala, import, compilation

When i compile I get this error:

```
blockmole.scala:4: error: '.' expected but ';' found.
object Color {
^
one error found
```

The error is somewhere inside this bit of code:

```
 package blockmole
 import JColor
 object Color {
   val black  = new JColor( 0,     0,     0)
   val mole   = new JColor( 51,    51,    0)
   val soil   = new JColor( 153,   102,   51)
   val tunnel = new JColor( 204,   153,   102)
 }
```

Comment: How can the error be within the above code, if the compiler says it found a ';', but there is no such character in the code above? Please post a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Striezel; the compiler inserts `;` at the end of lines. It's complaining that there isn't enough information to locate the `JColor` package/library.

Comment: where did you copy this code from?

Comment: Have you ensured that the library that defines `JColor` (it isn't a standard _Scala_ or _Java_ class) is on your path? Have you declared it as a dependency in your build file (if you're using _sbt_, this will be `build.sbt`; if you're using _Maven_, it will be `pom.xml`, etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

Your import statement is not complete. It assumes `JColor` is the base package name (which it is not). Use the full package path for the 'JColor' library and it should compile.

Comment: Do you happen to know how to complete it? Do you know the full path? I know a package ¨java.awt.Color¨ but it does not work. Thanks for quickly replying btw!

Answer (score 0):

`JColor` isn't a standard *Scala* or *Java* class. However, it looks like you're simply trying to create different color instances, and you don't much care which library defines those colors, right?

The *Java Abstract Window Toolkit* (*AWT*) is a little long in the tooth. You could use it's `Color` class, as follows:

```
package blockmole
import java.awt.{Color => AWTColor} // Rename to prevent name clash.
object Color {
  val black  = new AWTColor( 0,     0,     0)
  val mole   = new AWTColor( 51,    51,    0)
  val soil   = new AWTColor( 153,   102,   51)
  val tunnel = new AWTColor( 204,   153,   102)
}
```

Note that since `java.awt.Color` and your `Color` object have the same name, we have to rename one or the other to something different (such as renaming the former `AWTColor`, in this case) to prevent a collision.